# Pass parameter to node js API call?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am generating preauthorized links for files from an S3 bucket, but would like to pass in the file name to download as a parameter.

This is what my API looks like:

```
reports.get('/xxx', async (req, res) => {

  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();

  var params = { 
    Bucket: config.xxx,
    Key: 'xxx/xxx.json',
    Expires: 60 * 5
  }

  try {
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
      if(err)throw err;
      console.log(url)
      res.json(url);
    });
  }catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.toString());
  }
});
```

And this is how I call it from the front end:

```
getPreauthorizedLink(e){
    fetch(config.api.urlFor('xxx'))
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((url) => {

        console.log(url);
    });
}
```

How can I add a parameter to the API call and corresponding API method to pass the filename?

Comment: Are you using express on the server-side?

Comment: You could use a query parameter and read the filename from the request URL that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using `express` on your server side so you can simply add parameters in the request `URL` and then get them on the server side.

In frontend or on your client side you will call the Api like

```
fetch('/xxx/FileName')
```

And on the backend you will modify your route like

```
 reports.get('/xxx/:fileName', ..){
   var fileName = req.params.fileName
}
```

Also you don't want to require everytime you receive a request. So you better move `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');` outside your request handler.